# jQuery Ajax request - href target ends up outside tags

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am using jQuery to make an AJAX call. The call is procesed and returns data as expected, but when I use `$("#newsLetterForm").html(data);` the link address pops OUT of the `<a>` tags.

**The Ajax Request**

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    data: $dataToSend,
    datatype: 'html',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#newsletterForm').html('<img id="ajaxwait" src="/images/ajaxwait.gif" alt="waiting" />');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        $('#newsletterForm').html("Error: " + textStatus);
    },
    success: function(data, textstatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#newsletterForm').html(data);
    },          
    timeout: 3000,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://myurl.com',            
});
```

**Alert Return Data** - notice Support is in the  tags

```
 There was an error processing your request. Please send your request to 
<a href="foo.html" onclick="" onmouseover="" onmouseout="" />Support</a>
```

**Output to Browser** - notice that Support is *outside* of the  tags

```
    There was an error processing your request. Please send your request to 
<a href="foo.html" onclick="" onmouseover="" onmouseout="" /></a>Support
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you please show some or your code where you are making this html. B/c i think theres some mistakes in quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your anchor is being closed twice, or better explained, the opening anchor tag is self closing.
The response from the server should be:

```
<a href="foo.html" onclick="" onmouseover="" onmouseout="">Support</a>
```

Notice I used just ">" instead of "/>" before "Support"

Comment: Thank-you. Obvious answer in hindsight.

Comment: Sometimes it takes that extra set of eyes to find the small things.

Answer (score 0):

You have a ending comma `url: 'http://myurl.com',`

Try removing that.